# Is context.clearRect() really THAT expensive?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this piece of canvas animation that is exhibiting some weird characteristics:

http://jsbin.com/olasol/2/edit

I'm on the latest version of Chrome. I'm using Chrome's inbuilt FPS monitor (you can activate it by going to `about:flags`).
I have marked the line in the JavaScript section which I think is the potential culprit:

```
fallingctx.clear();
```

This line does nothing special. It calls a function which in-turn calls `clearRect()`.

The "weird" things I notice are:

1. The `clear();` function causes very noticeable FPS drop on my laptop (Core 2 Duo), but not on my desktop (i5 2500k).
2. Removing that line alone is sufficient to produce 60fps on my laptop as well. As expected, the canvas doesn't clear after each frame, but still, it produces stable 60fps.
3. The FPS drop happens only when my Chrome window is on the larger side! When I shrink the window and reload, it doesn't happen! (Is it more expensive to clear a larger rectangle?).
4. I tried replacing the `clear()` with a `drawImage()` of a full white JPEG to cover the canvas. The JavaScript is able to do 200 `drawImage()` executions each cycle for the smaller image particles (evident from the second point). However, when I add one single `drawImage` for the overall canvas, it lags again! (Make sure the output occupies the entire screen in order to reproduce the result.)

Why is all this happening? How do I fix it?

Comment: Note that the `window.requestAnimationFrame` thing doesn't really need to be in a function. Also, please don't use `new Object()`, and using the dot syntax for property access instead of brackets is probably a good idea.

Comment: Extending the prototype of that kind of thing is also probably something you shouldn't do.

Comment: So in a high-performance setting, you're extending a native object with a method that accesses `this.canvas`... that *may* cause some problems. Is this better at all? http://jsbin.com/olasol/12/edit

Comment: @rynah thanks for the help. and sadly, no. no noticeable improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *really* depends on the hardware, but  think about what the invocation of `clearRect` has to do!  Something essentially must zero-out a piece of memory large enough to handle the canvas contents.  That can be costly.  Think about how much memory has to hold RGBA at HD resolutions...  That's over two million pixels of data, around  8 MB in bytes  Admittedly, it's not all *that* much these days in general, but if there's any bandwidth or caching issues related to pushing memory to the video card or something you are doing 60 times a second... well, expect problems.

What I've heard often works is just to clear around where the image is formerly drawn.  See http://jsbin.com/olasol/6/edit

I made the following changes for you.

```
    for (var i=0; i< noOfDrops; ++i)
    {
        fallingctx.clearRect(
          fallingDrops[i].x-1,
          fallingDrops[i].y-1,
          fallingDrops[i].image.width+2,
          fallingDrops[i].image.height+2);
    }
    for (var i=0; i< noOfDrops; ++i)
    {
        fallingDrops[i].y += fallingDrops[i].speed; //Set the falling speed
        fallingctx.drawImage (fallingDrops[i].image, fallingDrops[i].x, fallingDrops[i].y);
    }
```

There's probably a good reason that I need to `clearRect` *around* where the image was rendered but a simple reason escapes me. (It is something to do with things being rendered not quite at the pixel specified... I forget exactly).

You also need to do something about the fact you are starting the render loop before the image is loaded (also in the jsbin) so I added

```
var imgSource = "http://lorempixel.com/20/20/sports/"; 
var imgObj = new Image();
```

and replaced `superinit`

```
function superinit()
{ 
    imgObj.onload = function(){
        flowerfallsetup();
        requestAnimFrame(flowerfall);
    }
    imgObj.onerror = function (){
        alert("could not load image");
    }
    imgObj.src = imgSource;
}
```

Edit: *I forgot to mention because of the prior image setup, I did change the line in your `flowerfallsetup` :*

```
      fallingDr["image"] = imgObj;
```

There are many ways to handle the asynchronous loading of images, I just chose one that was easy for this example.

Edit: I have to confess, there might be a bit more to this.  It works fine on desktop browsers, but on the iPhone, there *are* clipping issues. If I can figure out what's causing the problem I'll try to post an update.

Comment: Why would blitting an existing image onto the canvas be faster than clearing it?

Comment: okay, that seems to have solved my problem. But i found this:
http://phrogz.net/tmp/image_move_sprites_canvas.html

My laptop is faster in clearing pieces of the canvas instead of the whole thing(135fps vs 80fps) but my desktop is faster in clearing the whole thing!(200fps vs 170fps). any idea why? 
and thanks for the detailed answer :)

Comment: tested on my Nexus S- It is also faster in clearing just the images.(44Fps vs 31fps). this is confusing :|

Comment: @viswa: Does your desktop have better accelerated graphics than the other two? Clearing only what's needed could be faster with CPU-based canvas, whereas looping through the images is slower than using an accelerated clear on something more modern. Just a guess, though.